# Check if a table exists based on a column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We have a data collection program that dynamically creates tables for data storage based on the identity value from another table.  For example if 15 devices are created then the `Devices` table would have 15 entries (name, address, etc) and the `DeviceID` value would be say 134 - 149 then 15 tables would be created called `Dev134` through `Dev149`.

Occasionally an issue occurred where some DEV tables were deleted but the record in the device table was not deleted leaving a orphan entry in the devices table. I.e. there is a `DeviceID = 1245`, but there is no table `Dev1245`.

What we would like to do is go through the `Devices` table and see if there is a corresponding `Dev` table in the database, and if not list the `ID`.

I have done this through a separate program, pulling the `DeviceID`'s from the `Device` table into a list and then doing a

```
SELECT * 
FROM @DeviceID
```

(`@DeviceID = "Dev" + DeviceID`)

and if I get something I know it's there and if I return nothing it's missing but I was hoping to do this with a single select statement that would return the ID of the missing tables.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me. Why do you need tables dynamically named like this? That is a strong indication that the design is less than ideal. Seems like a single table to hold that data would be appropriate with one extra column to hold the identity value.

Comment: We are data logging devices and each device could have anywhere from 1 to 150 points of data being logged every 15 minutes.  There could be 1000+ devices per site and 50+ sites per server the software is running on.   Devices are rarely identical so you might have 30 with 45 points of data, 120 with 20 points of data.   A single table wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Not sure how those numbers mean you have to resort to a dynamic architecture. It still seems to me that there is a more standard approach to whatever it is you are trying to do that wouldn't require so much dynamic logic.

Comment: How would you take a infinite number of different devices with a different number of values of different data types and store them all into the same table??? It only makes sense logically to have a table per device.  If there were a set number of device types with the same points sure but there isn't which is why the tables, and columns themselves, are all dynamically created.

Comment: Either add each value as another row or use JSON, or maybe even XML.

Comment: For a single example device I have 130 points of data.  Logged every 15 minutes every day I have 350k+ values in a month.  I could either have all that data easily accessible in a single table called Dev1450 that doesn't require any extra column identifiers since the table name matches a entry in the Devices table or I could have that data intermingled with 10+ million other entries with extra columns to keep track of it in one massive table.  Dynamic makes the most sense, is easy to manage, and it's fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Dev'+CAST(deviceId AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM   devices
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name='Dev'+CAST(deviceId AS VARCHAR(10)));
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/NvKj66LQ)

Comment: Thank-you.  This worked perfectly and found a single device (out of 18k) in the tDevices table that was orphaned.

Answer (score 2):

You can select table information from `sys.tables`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

This statement should give you all entries which misses the corresponding table:

```
SELECT [devices].*
FROM Devices AS [devices]
LEFT JOIN sys.tables AS [tables]
    ON [devices].[name] = [tables].[name]
WHERE [tables].[name] IS NULL
```